# issue currency maj in opencart Version 3.0.2.0

Tags: php, opencart

I have a issue with currency in opencart 3.0.2.0.

When a change currency from euro to usd for example from header. catalog product currency note updated anymore.

you can check this here : prodaou.com

Answer (score 1):

I see. you are using Journal 3 template. And your issue can be seen only on the home page with **Latest** module. It is Journsl 3 chase issue, which was fixed on 3.0.2 version (Currency Cache fix) https://docs.journal-theme.com/changelog.

Update your Journal 3 theme. Don't forget to backup first.

Comment: You can write here. In comments. Can you download fresh Journal theme from a place you have bought it?